# Rank one abelian subgroups.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group such that all rank 1 abelian subgroups are isomorphic to $Z$. Is there a name in group theory describing this property?

$Z$ and any free groups has this property. What are some other examples of groups with this property.

Comment: Certainly any (torsion free) abelian group with no $p$-divisible subgroups for any prime $p$ would provide an example. There exist examples of these which are not free.

Comment: Do you have any motivation to study such groups? Ad hoc it crosses my mind that torsion-free hyperbolic groups are examples (this class contains free groups) . Indeed for such groups all finitely generated abelian subgroups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.